# jruby on rails with jdbc

Tags: jrubyonrails

Hy,

I am a new in JRuby on Rails. I installed RadRails and many gems:

pieces of gems

- activerecord (2.3.4)
- ActiveRecord-JDBC (0.5)
- activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9)
- activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.9)
- jdbc-mysql (5.1.24)

book: http://koti.kapsi.fi/jamo/priv2/JRuby%20on%20Rails,%202007.pdf

I read the following section called "Store Administration" in chapter 4 and I modified my config/database.yml to this:

```
development:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://my_host/my_database
  username: my_user
  password: my_pass
```

I added to build path the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Aptana RadRails\plugins\org.jruby_1.2.0.9419p2\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\jdbc-mysql-5.1.24\
```

When I restarted the server I got the following error:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  The driver encountered an error: cannot load Java class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    C:/Program Files/Aptana RadRails/plugins/org.jruby_1.2.0.9419p2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ActiveRecord-JDBC-0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:265:in `initialize'
    C:/Program Files/Aptana RadRails/plugins/org.jruby_1.2.0.9419p2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ActiveRecord-JDBC-0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:41:in `jdbc_connection'
```

I would like to ask your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jdbc jar to your class path? Try copying the jar file directly to the `lib` directory under your jruby installation.

e.g. `C:\jruby\lib\mysql-jdbc.jar`.